# Laravel Seeding DB with a model that has multiple relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I really struggled coming up with a solution to the problem where a model has a one to many relationship with users AND companies.  This appears to work but I'm pretty sure it's not the best way.  This is inside the `run()` method of the `UsersTableSeeder`.

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\User::class, 10)
        ->create()
        ->each(function ($user) {
            $user->companies()->saveMany(
                factory(App\Company::class, 10)->create(['user_id' => $user->id])->each(function($company) use ($user) {
                    $company->jobs()->save(factory(App\Job::class)->make([
                        'user_id' => $user->id,
                        'company_id' => $company->id,
                    ]));
                })
            );
    });
}
```

In the above case a job has a `user_id` and a `company_id`.  What would be a better (simpler) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could get a random `id` from the company and user model. Like this:

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\User::class, 10)
        ->create()
        ->each(function ($user) {
            $user->companies()->saveMany(
                factory(App\Company::class, 10)->create(['user_id' => $user->id])->each(function($company) use ($user) {
                    $company->jobs()->save(factory(App\Job::class)->make([
                        'user_id' => App\User::all()->random()->id,
                        'company_id' => App\Company::all()->random()->id,
                    ]));
                })
            );
    });
}
```

Comment: The code I posted works but what I was trying to get at was that it seems really complicated.  Imagine for example that the jobs model has 8 relationships.  I was just thinking there would be a cleaner way to do multiple relationships.  Thank you!